# Cannot access JSON elements in Golang code

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have the following Golang code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"   
    "strings"
)

func someFunc() {
    output := `
    {
        "predictions": [
          {
            "displayNames": [
              "AAA",
              "BBB",
              "CCC",
              "DDD",
              "EEE",
              "FFF",
              "GGG",
              "HHH"
            ],
            "confidences": [
              0.99998986721038818,
              5.3742646741739009e-06,
              1.7922732240549522e-06,
              1.5455394475338835e-07,
              3.2323268328582344e-07,
              6.80681324638499e-08,
              9.2994454803374538e-08,
              2.317885900993133e-06
            ],
            "ids": [
              "552624439724867584",
              "7470153467365949440",
              "6317231962759102464",
              "8911305348124508160",
              "4011388953545408512",
              "2858467448938561536",
              "5164310458152255488",
              "1705545944331714560"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "deployedModelId": "ABC123",
        "model": "myOwnModel",
        "modelDisplayName": "myDisplayName",
        "modelVersionId": "1"
    }`
    var outputJson map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(output), &outputJson)

    // names := outputJson["predictions"].(data)[0].(data)["displayNames"].(data)
    // ids := outputJson["predictions"].(data)[0].(data)["ids"].(data)
    // confidences := outputJson["predictions"].(data)[0].(data)["confidences"].(data)
    // fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("Names:\n%s\n", names))
    // fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("IDs:\n%s\n", ids))
    // fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("Confidences:\n%s\n", confidences))

    fmt.Println("something")
}

func main() {
    someFunc()
}
```

I want to access the `displayNames`, `ids`, and `confidences` elements from `outputJson`.  I use VS Code to check their locations, and add them to the watch list.

[image: img]

I then copy the location strings into my code.  However, it doesn't work as shown in the picture.  The complain is that `data` is undefined.  Why is this happening, and what can I do to access these elements?  Why does this `data` works in the watch window, but not in the code?

Comment: That is the internal field of the interface. You cannot access that. But its type is `map[string]interface{}` for one case and `[]interface{}` for another, so you can type-assert to the actual type and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [type assert](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15) your way through the `outputJson`:

```golang
p := outputJson["predictions"]
if x, ok := p.([]interface{}); ok {
    if y, ok := x[0].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
        fmt.Println(y["displayNames"])
    }
}
```

But, a better approach, given that you don't need to decode arbitrary JSON, is to define a tree of Golang types and then unmarshal into it:

```
type Output struct {
    Predictions []Prediction `json:"predictions"`
}
type Prediction struct {
    DisplayNames []string `json:"displayNames"`
    // Confidences ...
}

func main() {

    ...
    foo := &Output{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(output), foo); err == nil {
        fmt.Println(foo.Predictions[0].DisplayNames)
    }
}
```